# Non-holonomic constraints, degree of freedom and generalized coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

If a system has $N$ coordinates and $M$ number of holonomic constraints then number of degree of freedom $=N-M$  and generalized coordinates $=N-M$ too. But if there are $k$ non-holonomic constraints then what will be no. of degree of freedom and generalized coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider a classical point-mechanical system with $3N$ coordinates but only $n$ [generalized coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) $(q^1, \ldots,q^n)$, because of $3N-n$ [holonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints).
2. Let us for simplicity assume that:

   - All constraints are 2-sided, i.e. we do *not* allow 1-sided constraints (= inequalities).
   - All non-holonomic constraints are [semi-holonomic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451).
3. If furthermore the system has $m$ semi-holonomic constraints, then we introduce $m$ [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) $(\lambda^1, \ldots,\lambda^m)$. The corresponding $n$ Lagrange equations are outlined in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. The number of [degrees of freedom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8860/2451) (DOF) are conventionally defined as half the number of initial conditions needed for $(q^1, \ldots,q^n,\dot{q}^1, \ldots,\dot{q}^n)$, which is then $n\!-\!m/2$, which curiously could be a half-integer. (The main point is that since each semi-holonomic constraint is a 1st-order [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation), they each remove the need of 1 initial condition.)