# How to derive the linear form of Pfaffian equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am working on fundamental dynamics in last few days. The question is about Pfaffian constraint.

A general form of Pfaffian constraint is
$$ A(q)^{\mathrm{T}}d{q} + b(q)dt = 0\tag{1}$$
which is formed as
$$ A(q)^{\mathrm{T}} \delta q = 0\tag{2}$$ with variation theorem, i.e. $$b(q)dt=0.\tag{3}$$

However, in some applications such as non-holonomic system, that the Pfaffain form is simply given by
$$A(q)^{\mathrm{T}}\dot{q} = 0.\tag{4}$$
I simply want the detailed derivation of this form. After searching internet, I didn't find too much things helpful to the derivation of this form.

Comment: Which some applications? Which pages?

Comment: @Qmechanic  That could be a lot if we search with keywords like non-holonomic  constraints and Pfaffian.

Answer (score 0):

1. The [semi-holonomic/Pfaffian constraint](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451) (1) is equivalent to
   $$ A(q)^{\mathrm{T}}\dot{q} +b(q)~=~ 0;\tag{1'} $$
   not eq. (4).
2. However, when considering [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle), time is frozen
   $$\delta t~=~0,$$
   so that an infinitesimal [virtual displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement) $\delta q$ satisfies eq. (2).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how (4) is derived. In (4) it is not a variation $$\delta.$$ Instead, it is a $$\dot{q}.$$