# Definition/classification of holonomic and non-holonomic constraints

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, constrained-dynamics

I am a mathematics student. I have Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics as an elective I have taken in this sem. Today I had a test in which I was asked a question:

> 1. A ball is constrained to move inside a spherical cage. The constraint imposed by the cage is (a) Non-holonomic  (b) Holonomic  (c) Rheonomic  (d) None of these.

I gave the answer as none of these as I thought that constraints imposed by an inequality $r\leq a$ (where $r$ denotes distance from origin and a denotes radius of sphere) is unilateral in nature.
But I am told that the answer would be non-holonomic.
Now I was a bit confused as nothing was mentioned about the velocity or time or anything on which the motion would depend inside the sphere. What should be the answer? Is non-holonomic correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ref. 1 defines a *non-holonomic constraint* as the opposite of a [holonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints).
2. Ref. 1 mentions that inequalities (aka. one-sided constraints) are examples of non-holonomic constraints.
3. For completeness, let us also mention [semi-holonomic constraints](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451).

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Section 1.3.