# Can someone explain the steps?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, classical-field-theory

Can anybody expand the equation .What is ω and is i power of ω in equation 2.2.
And how $f_λ(r_1,r_2,...,r_n,t)=0$;λ=1,2,...,Λ gives the last equation and what $∇_k$ means?
[image]

Comment: What is equation 2.1?

Comment: This is explained in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451).

Comment: @Alwin $f_λ(r_1, r_2, . . . , r_n, t) = 0 ;λ = 1, 2, . . . , Λ $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are holonomic and non-holonomic constraints?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409951/)