# Lagrangian energy equation with a nonholonomic constraint?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

Problem 6.8 on p. 39 in [David Morin's The Lagrangian Method](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjMud2P3Zf-AhUoQ_EDHcE3ABAQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscholar.harvard.edu%2Ffiles%2Fdavid-morin%2Ffiles%2Fcmchap6.pdf&usg=AOvVaw22KewRyLXcEOMoAkH43l8U) gives a stick pivoted at the origin and rotating around the pivot with constant angular velocity $\dot{\alpha}$ (which is given as $\omega$ in the document). A small mass $m$ can slide frictionless along the stick. The problems asks to find the conserved energy of the system, which it gives as $$E=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2-r^2\dot{\alpha}^2)$$ in the solutions.

My question is not how to obtain the solution, which I understand for this problem. My questions are related to generalized coordinates and constraints used here to see if I understood the methodology for more complex systems.

At first I made the mistake to consider two generalized coordinates $q_1=r$ and $q_2=\alpha$, because it felt natural to consider all velocities ($\dot{r}$ and $\dot{\alpha}$) when dealing with energies.

It turned out that the problem has two constraints ($m=2$) and one particle ($n=1$), which leaves me with just one generalized coordinate ($S=3n-m=1$). My first constraint is $z=0$.

My second constraint should be $\alpha - \dot{\alpha}t=0$.

Is this second constraint chosen correctly and is it an example of nonholonomic constraints, because it depends on a velocity?

Do I always obtain a wrong result when choosing more generalized coordinates than I have degrees of freedom? I could think of this problem very general without constraining $\dot{\alpha}$ at all. Once I have a solution for the conserved energy, I could make different assumptions like $\dot{\alpha}=const$ or $\dot{r}=const$ to see how the conserved energy changes with different assumptions. But then I would have used more general coordinates during my problem description than I have degrees of freedom through my assumptions, which would be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OP's constraint
$$\dot{\alpha}~=~\omega \tag{S}$$
is [semi-holonomic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451) & non-holonomic but integrable, and in fact equivalent to a [holonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints)
$$\alpha~=~\omega t +{\rm const.}\tag{H} $$

Comment: thanks. But is the constraint you've given not dependent on $\dot{\alpha}$ ($=\omega$) and as such not a holonomic constraint by definition?