# Connection between different kinds of "Lagrangian"

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

Being a physic student I first heard the term: "*Lagrangian*" during a course about Lagrangian mechanics; at that time this term was defined to me in the following way:

> For a classic, non relativistic, mechanical system, the *Lagrangian* ($\mathcal{L}$) is a function, defined as the **difference** between kinetic energy (*K*) and potential energy (*V*):
> $$\mathcal{L} := K-V. \tag{1}$$

This definition is consistent with what we find in the [related section of the Wikipedia page regarding Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics#Introduction).

Soon after I learned that the Lagrangian can also be defined in contexts that aren't strictly classical or mechanical, one good example of such context is the Lagrangian in presence of an EM field; but here definition (1) doesn't hold anymore. We need to redefine the Lagrangian in the following way:

> The *Lagrangian* is  **any** function which generates the correct equations of motion once plugged into *Euler-Lagrange* equation:
> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left ( \frac {\partial  L}{\partial \dot{x}} \right ) =  \frac {\partial L}{\partial x}.\tag{2}$$

This, way more cloudy, definition is also reported in the related Wikipedia page. This new way of defining the Lagrangian came as a shock to me, since it seems to me as a ***non*-definition**. But fair enough. This second way of defining the term *Lagrangian* is of course consistent with our first definition; it's a **generalization** of our previous definition (1).

But then I stumbled upon a **third** definition for the term *Lagrangian*: in the context of [the method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) (a field strongly related with Lagrangian mechanics) the *Lagrangian* is defined in the following way:

> Given the function $f(x)$ that we want to **maximize**, and given the equation $g(x)=0$ that represents our **constraints**; the *Lagrangian* is defined as the following function:
> $$\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) := f(x)-\lambda g(x).\tag{3}$$

**My question is:** Why is this last function called *Lagrangian*? Is it just a coincidence? Is there a link between our first two definitions of *Lagrangian* and this last third definition? Is the *Lagrangian* in the context of Lagrangian mechanics in some way the same thing as the *Lagrangian* in the context of the Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: I would say that the second definition is not a non-definition because it is not at all obvious that such a quantity ought to exist that would produce the correct equations of motion when plugged into the EL equations. The non-trivial nature of the definition lies in the non-triviality of the existence of such objects.

Comment: @DvijD.C.  That said, the problem is, for relativstic and quantum mechanical systems, it is often non-obvious what parts of the Lagrangian are "T" and which parts are "V", right (for instance, where is the T and V in $\sqrt{-g}R$?)? The Lagrangian really is the first-order thing.  So, what's the definition of the lagrangian in this case?

Comment: Joseph-Louis Lagrange had a long life, and he did many different things. You will find lots of concepts that go by the name of "Lagrange/Lagrangian".

Comment: Nature *minimizes* [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) subject to the *constraints* of physical laws e.g. Newton's laws or Maxwell's laws. So it's not even the least bit surprising that Lagrange multipliers and the Lagrangian used in the Eurler Lagrange equations are related concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP's question is a quite broad topic, which is better studied in textbooks, such as Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics,* but let's give a few pointers:

1. OP's definition (1) of a Lagrangian as $L=T-U$ is not the most general, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461559/2451) Phys.SE posts. Although for huge classes of theories, it is actually true, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. OP's definition (2) of an Lagrangian in [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) is equivalent to the [principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action). EL equations state that the [functional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) of the action vanish. Note however, that more generally, Lagrange equations may not arise from a variational principle, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. OP's definition (3) from the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) [to optimize *finitely* many variables on a constraint surface] is as stated *not* really about [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) per se.

   As there are no $\dot{x}$, eq. (3) represents a *static* problem with no time and no kinetic energy. Nevertheless, one may view the "Lagrangian" (3) as (minus) a potential energy. The functional derivative in EL eqs. gets replaced by a partial derivative.

   Finally it should be mentioned that Lagrange multiplier fields $\lambda(t)$ [that depends on $t$] are often used in action formulations for dynamical systems to implement constraints, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/590960/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 8):

The first two definitions of the Lagrangian are not equivalent but very closely related in the sense that one is a generalization of the other.

The second one may be a non-definition, but that can be easily helped with. I would argue that it is more logically sound to define a Lagrangian in the context of variation problems rather than in physics.

The connection with physics is that you want to specify the dynamical equation of your system as a variational problem and specifically one which can be formulated in terms of a Lagrangian (there are more general variation problems where the "Lagrangian" is nonlocal/not of finite order).

---

The third definition is different. Of course it is also related in the sense that in Lagrangian formulations of dynamics or variational problems, Lagrange multiplier methods often appear. But this third definition of a Lagrangian gets its name because of *Lagrange* multipliers, rather than because they are in any ways related to Lagrangians of variational problems.

I am not the best person to talk about historical aspects but probably both get the name Lagrangian because [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph-Louis_Lagrange) played an important part in their discovery or popularization through application.

Just like in differential geometry half of the things that appear are named after Cartan but not all of those are related or the same.

Answer (score 4):

I will first discuss why in classical dynamics the form (kinetic energy *minus* potential energy) works out as  being an effective Lagrangian. After that I will discuss how to apply the underlying pattern to other areas of physics. That is, what in *general* it takes to be an effective Lagrangian.

For Classical mechanics I start with the Work-Energy theorem:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s F ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2   \qquad (1) $$

The amount of *change* of kinetic energy is galilean invariant, hence the Work-Energy theorem is valid only for forces such that the change of velocity that they cause is independent of the current velocity.

As we know: a force that satisfies the Work-Energy theorem is referred to as a *conservative force*. Gravity: independent of whether you are moving down the potential gradient or up the gradient: the *change* in kinetic energy is the same, hence the change of potential is the same; hence the property: conservative.

When the force that is involved satisfies the work-Energy theorem we have the following:

$$ d(E_k) = d(-E_p) \qquad (2) $$

The sum of kinetic energy and potential energy is constant, hence at every moment the *rate of change* of kinetic energy matches the *rate of change* of potential energy. For any decrease of potential energy there is a matching increase of kinetic energy.

(Note especially that this assertion is narrower in scope than the principle of conservation of energy. The Work-Energy theorem is applicable only for *conservative forces*. )

(2) can be stated as a differential equation in two ways:

$$ \frac{d(E_k)}{dt} = \frac{d(-E_p)}{dt} \qquad (3) $$

$$ \frac{d(E_k)}{ds} = \frac{d(-E_p)}{ds} \qquad (4) $$

Of the above two (4) is the practical way forward. On the right hand side of (4) you have the derivative-over-distance of the potential energy. The potential energy is the integral-over-distance of the force, so the right hand side of (4) is the force. That is: (4)  is another way of expressing $F=ma$.

What is been gained is that by formulating the physics taking place in terms of energies you have all of the expressive power of using *generalized coordinates* available. The importance of being able to use generalized coordinates cannot be overstated.

If you insert the expression $E_k - E_p$ into the Euler-Lagrange equation then the resulting expression is mathematically equivalent to (4).

The Euler-Lagrange equation does a comparison of two contributions that are in flux: a quantity that is a function of current *spatial coordinate*, and a quantity that is a function of current *velocity*.

So: in the case of classical mechanics the Euler-Lagrange equation imposes the same constraint as (4) does: the rate of change of kinetic energy must match the rate of change of potential energy.

Note that (2) explains the *minus sign* in the Lagrangian for classical mechanics. What is evaluated is not the kinetic/potential energy itself, but the *derivative* of the kinetic/potential energy.

So: how to transfer the underlying idea to other areas of physics?

The nature of the Euler-Lagrange equation is that it does - in the form of a differential equation - a comparison of a function of *spatial coordinate* on one hand to a *time-derivative-of-spatial coordinate* on the other hand. (These coordinates can be generalized coordinates, as fitting for any particular case.)

(From here on I will refer to time-derivative-of-spatial-coordinate generically as 'velocity'.)

That is why the "Lagrangian" that is inserted into the Euler-Lagrange equation tends to be specific to the area of physics you are dealing with.

In classical mechanics the underlying pattern is that for *conservative forces* by definition the sum of potential energy and kinetic energy is a constant, hence (2), hence (4)

In another area of physics: whatever you insert into the Euler-Lagrange equation, it must have the property that during the entire time something that is a function of *spatial coordinate* is matching something that is a function of *velocity*.

For the sake of completeness: the demonstration that the spatial derivative of kinetic energy is equivalent to mass times acceleration.

$$ \frac{d(\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{ds} = \tfrac{1}{2}m\left( 2v\frac{dv}{ds} \right) = m\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{dv}{ds} = m\frac{dv}{dt} \qquad (5) $$

---

[Later edit]
(5 hours after submitting this answer)

Here I give the demonstration that inserting the Lagrangian $E_k - E_p$ in the Euler-Lagrange equation is equivalent to (4).

The expression stated in terms of partial derivatives:

$$ \frac {\partial(E_k - E_p)}{\partial s} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac {\partial(E_k - E_p)}{\partial v} = 0 \qquad (6) $$

Potential energy is a function of position only, and kinetic energy is a function of velocity only, hence:

$$ \frac {d(-E_p)}{ds} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac {d(E_k)}{dv} = 0  \qquad (7) $$

The term with the potential energy is already identical to the one in (4).
Evaluating the term with kinetic energy:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\frac{d (\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2)}{d v} = m\frac{d}{dt}v = m\frac{dv}{dt}  \qquad (8) $$

This completes the demonstation that inserting the Lagrangian $E_k - E_p$ in the Euler-Lagrange equation gives an equation that is mathematically equivalent to (4).

With (4) in place we have everything. We have that all the expressive power of using generalized coordinates is available. We can apply the Legendre transform to transform between Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics. So we have everything.

There is a worthhwile piece of information to add: to explain what the relation is between Lagrangian mechanics and Hamilton's stationary action.

**Variational calculus**

There is a lemma in variational calculus, first stated by Jacob Bernoulli (In an earlier answer I have proposed to name it 'Jacob's Lemma'.)

When Johann Bernoulli had presented the [Brachistochrone problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve) to the mathematicians of the time Jacob Bernoulli was among the few who solved it. The treatment by Jacob Bernoulli is in the Acta Eruditorum, May 1697, pp. 211-217

Jacob opens his treatment with an observation concerning the fact that the curve that is sought is a minimum.

[image: Jacob Bernoulli Brachistochrone]

*Lemma*. Let ACEDB be the desired curve along which a heavy point falls from A to B in the shortest time, and let C and D be two points on it as close together as we like. Then the segment of arc CED is among all segments of arc with C and D as end points the segment that a heavy point falling from A traverses in the shortest time. Indeed, if another segment of arc CFD were traversed in a shorter time, then the point would move along AGFDB in a shorter time than along ACEDB, which is contrary to our supposition.

This lemma generalizes to any curve property for which an extremum is sought.

The curve that is the solution to the variational problem has the following property: it is not only an extremal along the entire curve, it is also an extremal along any *subsection* of the curve, down to infinitisimally short subsections.

This means - among other things - that without loss of validity the variation space can be reduced to a linear variation space. That is, the variation can be expressed in terms of a single variational parameter $p_v$

(trial trajectory) = (1 + $p_v$)(true trajectory)

The variation is a *spatial variation*. Since the variation space is *linear* the following two are identical:
derivative with respect to variation
derivative with respect to position

I repeat the differential equation with the derivatives of the respective energies with respect to position:

$$ \frac{d(E_k)}{ds} = \frac{d(-E_p)}{ds} \qquad (9) $$

Integration is a *linear* operation. If (9) is satisfied then following equation is automatically satisfied also:

$$ \frac{(\int E_k dt)}{ds} = \frac{(\int -E_p dt)}{ds} \qquad (10) $$

Given that derivative with respect to variation and derivative with respect to position are the same: (10) is equivalent to stating Hamilton's stationary action.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder It's gratifying to see you give this answer three exclamation marks. In my opinion this is how Lagrange should have derived Lagrangian mechanics from first principles. (Why Lagrange chose the arduous route of evaluating *virtual work* is mysterious. The way ahead is  straightforward: use work, instead of virtual work.) There's more on my own website. (Link to my website is available on my profile page. I'm not linking directly so as to avoid the appearance of vanity linking.)

Comment: There are some nice animations on your website! The ones with the epicycles give a good feeling of the corresponding physics.

Comment: Did you drop an $m$ in your first equation?

Comment: -1: This talks a lot about Lagrangian mechanics, but does not address OP's actual question, which is whether and how this relates to the method of Lagrange multipliers in constrained optimization.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer addresses the question in a way that makes you see the underlying mechanism. And look at the effort taken...

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I explained the DV in my comment. Yes, a well-written answer to a different question. Seems to have read the question as relating $K - V$ to more general Lagrangian mechanics. But OP clearly says at the end that the question is how *either* of these relates to the third "Lagrangian", the one with a *Lagrange multiplier*.

Comment: @KingLogic Yeah, 'm' for 'mass' was missing. I have corrected it.

Comment: @nanoman I concur that I shifted the focus. The question about Lagrange multipliers is a mathematics question, not a physics question; it didn't even occur to me to go into it. My focus: the OP is very suspicious of the *non-definition* of 'Lagrangian', and rightly so. To understand why in different areas of physics a different Lagrangian is useful it must be understood why in classical mechanics $E_k - E_P$ is the Lagrangian that reproduces $F=ma$. The EL-equation is a tool, like a slide rule is a tool. In order to use the tool effectively one must understand the tool.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian develops a very intuitive meaning within the action principle (aka Hamilton's principle). Without further, accompanying interpretation, of which there are many (e.g. principle of virtual work), some of them only of historic interest (Maupertuis' principle, etc.), but which are mostly equivalent, the Lagrangian is meaningless.

The action principle tells us, that the solution to the corresponding equations of motion (the Euler-Lagrange equations) is found by optimizing the action
$$S=\int L dx$$
where $x$ can be just time (in classical mechanics) or spacetime (in field theory).

The fact that pre-given equations of motion (differential equations) can be cast into an action principle (and with that, a Lagrangian), is non-trivial. Not all differential equations satisfy this requirement. A prominent counter example are equations that are not energy conserving, i.e. include some form of dissipation ("friction" or "viscosity"). Vice-versa, the action principle guarantees energy conservation (and momentum conservation, and charge conservation, etc.) under minimal requirements (i.e. a Lagrangian that is not explicitly time dependent, for the case of energy conservation). So the Lagrangian is far from being a non-definition.

The Lagrange multipliers on the other hand are a mathematical technique for generally considering constraint equations given with a specific optimization problem. Since the action principle **is** an optimization problem, Lagrange multipliers can be applied to the action principle. However, they can also be applied to other optimization problems, that have nothing to do with energy conservation and such, nor even with physical problems. But when applied to the action principle, the method of Lagrange multipliers leads to a **Lagrangian** that contains **Lagrange multipliers**, just in the form that you have cited in the last part of your question. The fact, that both these different things are connected with the name of "Lagrange", is the real coincidence. He obviously was a very active mathematician/physicist.

Comment: One can reach a perfectly valid interpretation of the Lagrangian starting from the principle of virtual work and completely ignoring any action integral.  The Lagrangian formulation based on virtual work can be generalized to include non-conservative forces (as you point out) something done with much much greater difficulty in the action formulation.  Thus suggesting that the Lagrangian “develops its meaning *only* within an action principle” is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: That is, of course, true. However, from this point of view it is much harder to justify the connection to the Lagrange multipliers. I mean, there is certainly an exotic derivation of Lagrange multipliers in Goldstein or whatnot, that does again not require an action principle, but ask any mathematician, and he will point you directly to constrained optimization. But maybe I am just a bit biased against non-action formulations of mechanics (in fact I hated all of them because of their mathematical awkwardness... :-) )

Comment: Another reason why I am biased against alternative interpretations of the Lagrangian is that they don't play a role in field theory (which I am most interested in), at least to my knowledge.

Comment: I changed my statement to something more neutral.

Comment: Right.  Regrettably for you there is much more to physics than field theory.   I agree with your modified statement: the action formulation is much more elegant and intuitive *when it can be used*.