# Lagrange equations for non-holonomic monogenic system

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

For [monogenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system) and a special case of non-holonomic constraints where we have$$
\sum_{k} a_{l k} d q_{k}+a_{t t} d t=0 \tag{2-20}
$$
we use lagrange multipliers and hamiltons principle to reach the below equation:

Goldstein, 2 edition

> $$\frac{d}{d t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{k}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{k}}=\sum_{l} \lambda_{l} a_{l k}, \quad k=1,2, \ldots, n.\tag{2-29}$$

And he says further

> What is the physical significance of the $\lambda_{i}$ 's? Suppose one removed the constraints on the system, but instead applied external forces $Q_{k}^{\prime}$ in such a manner as to keep the motion of the system unchanged. The equations of motion would likewise remain the same. Clearly these extra applied forces must be equal to the forces of constraint, for they are the forces applied to the system so as to satisfy the condition of constraint. Under the influence of these forces $Q_{k}^{\prime}$, the equations of motion are
> $$
> \frac{d}{d t} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{k}}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{k}}=Q_{k}^{\prime}.\tag{2-31}
> $$
> But these must be identical with Eqs. (2-29). Hence we can identify $\sum \lambda_{1} a_{l k}$ with $Q_{k}^{\prime}$, the generalized forces of constraint.

**Question**: How does it follow that
"Under the influence of these forces $Q_{k}^{\prime}$, the equations of motion are eq. (2-31)?"

Since we've a monogenic system, potential maybe a function of velocities $V=V(r,\dot r,t)$ therefore replacing constraints by equivalent forces and using d'Alemberts  principle we might get $$\frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}_{j}}\right)-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_{j}}=Q_{j}$$ and not
eq. (2-31).

Can anyone shed some light please.

Answer (score 1):

1. Goldstein is talking about [semi-holonomic constraints](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410110/2451); *not* general non-holonomic constraints, such as, e.g. inequalities.
2. Goldstein's treatment of semi-holonomic constraints via a [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle) has already been criticize in e.g. Ref. 3. and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/343456/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510966/2451) related Phys.SE posts.
3. To be specific, let us from now on only consider the 2nd edition of Goldstein.
4. We should stress that the result (2-29) is correct. For a generalization, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.
5. One may consider the constraint forces $\sum_{l} \lambda_{l} a_{l k}$ on the RHS of eq. (2-29) as examples of [generalized forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_forces), cf. eq. (2-31). This point is possibly one of OP's doubts.
6. It seems Goldstein implicitly and unnecessarily assumes that all the non-constraint forces are [monogenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_system), i.e. that they have generalized (possibly velocity-dependent) potentials, cf. eq. (1-58).
7. OP seems to mistakenly assume that the constraint forces are also monogenic, and/or that all forces are constraint forces. Both are not the case.
8. To prove eq. (2-29) we need to establish eq. (2-23), or more generally, eq. (1-52).
9. Goldstein is now criticized for using [Hamilton's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle) (2-2). The issue is that one cannot just enforce the semi-holonomic constraints via Lagrange multipliers in an extended stationary action principle, cf. point 2.
10. We will instead rely on [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) (1-45). A minor modification of eqs. (2-24)-(2-28) and the surrounding arguments then leads to the result (2-29).

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* 2nd edition; Section 2.4.
2. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* 3rd edition; Section 2.4.
3. M.R. Flannery, *The enigma of nonholonomic constraints,*
   [Am. J. Phys. 73 (2005) 265](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.1830501).

Comment: I'm studying it.

Answer (score 1):

**EL with non holonomic constraint equations**
\begin{align*}
 &\text{you have $~n_w~$non holonomic  constraint equations}\\
&F_{w}=F_w({\dot{q}}_1~, q_1~,\ldots~,{\dot{q}}_s~, q_s)=0~,w=1..n_w\tag 1\\\\
&\text{EL equations with Langrange  multiplier $~\lambda _w$  }\\
&\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\dot{q}}_i}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial  q_i}=\underbrace{\sum_{w=1}^{n_w} a_{(i,w)}\,\lambda_w}_{Q_i}~,i=1..s\tag 2\\
&\text{where}\\
&a_{(w,i)}=\frac{\partial F_w}{\partial \dot q_i}
\end{align*}
Instead of Eq. (1) and (2) you applied the EL with external forces

\begin{align*}
  &\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\dot{q}}_i}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial  q_i}=\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^{s}\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}f_j}_{\bar Q_{i}}~,i=1..s\tag 3\\
  &\text{where $~f_j~$ are the non conservative external force components}~f_j=f_j(\mathbf q~,\mathbf{\dot{q}})\\
&\text{and $~r_i~$  the position vector components}
\end{align*}
**notice** that the conservative forces are equal to  $-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_i}$ where U is the potential enegry

Eq. (3) is equal to Eq. (1) and (2)  if $~\bar Q_i=Q_i~$  and the constraint equation (1) is fulfilled, this is what Prof. Golstein  wrote ?

Comment: How do you get equation 3 ?

Comment: The position vector  r is function of the generalized coordinates    $f_{i}\rightarrow \sum ^{s}_{j=1}\dfrac{\partial r_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}f_j$ I shall update the dok.

Comment: Thank you .....